# Could antioxidants be lost significantly during drying of blueberries or mulberries?

Tags: nutrient-composition, drying, blueberries

I heard that blueberries and mulberries contain antioxidants beneficial for human beings, such as anthocyanins, or oligomer proantho cyanidins.

I was wondering if there is a lot of nutrient difference between their raw or dried versions.
Could antioxidants be lost significantly during drying of blueberries or mulberries, by sunlight, heat, etc?